# History of logarithmic potential

Tags: mathematics, physics

I have some historical questions in connections for the notes to a book I am writing.

Who the first person to discover that the Coulomb potential in two dimension is $\log(|x|^{-1})$, equivalently that this is essentially the fundamental solution for the 2D Poisson equation? I'm guessing it might have been Poisson in one of his remarkable papers between 1817 and 1818. These papers are not readily available to me.

Also who first used the term logarithmic potential?

I'm also interested in the discrete case. My understanding is that the discrete fundamental solution was first discussed in Polya's famous 1921 paper on recurrence in random walks. Can anyone confirm that and if that is also the place where the $\log(n)$ asymptotics was found (so far as I can see from skimming his paper with my almost non-existent German, all he used is that it goes to infinity).

Comment: Re "Poisson in one of his remarkable papers between 1817 and 1818" Could you cite these publications, please? They *may* be available as scans online, but I am having trouble identifying relevant publications by Poisson in the stated timeframe. Could you likewise cite "Polya's famous 1921 paper"?

Comment: Here is a scan of one of his papers from 1817: Poisson, "Sur la forme des intégrales des équations aux différences partielles." *Bulletin des sciences / par la Société philomathique de Paris*, 1817, [pp. 180-183](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/25915#page/186/mode/1up)

Comment: Poisson, "Remarques sur les rapports qui existent entre la propagation des ondes à la surface de l'eau, et leur propagation dans une plaque élastique." *Bulletin des sciences / par la Société philomathique de Paris*, 1818, [pp. 97-99](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/24834#page/105/mode/1up)

Comment: Poisson, "Sur l'intégrale de l'équation relative aux vibrations des plaques élastiques."
*Bulletin des sciences / par la Société philomathique de Paris*, 1818, [pp. 125-128](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/24834#page/133/mode/1up)

Comment: Poisson, "Mémoire sur le mouvement des fluides élastiques dans les tuyaux cylindriques, et sur la théorie des instruments à vent." *Bulletin des sciences / par la Société philomathique de Paris*, 1818, [pp. 43-45](https://www.biodiversitylibrary.org/item/24834#page/51/mode/1up)

Comment: It seems this is the only paper by Pólya from 1921 dealing with random walks: Georg Pólya, "Über eine Aufgabe der Wahrscheinlichkeitsrechnung betreffend die Irrfahrt im Straßennetz." *Mathematische Annalen*, Vol. 84, [pp. 149-160](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN235181684_0084?tify=%7B%22pages%22%3A%5B152%5D%2C%22view%22%3A%22info%22%7D)

Comment: Thanks njuffra - those seem to be the papers.